# How to fix minecraft server error where files are compiled by an older version of java

Tags: java, minecraft

The full error is - UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0

I first got it when trying to update old servers, this is from a fabric server and I get the same thing when running it on my own machine with no third party.

Java is fully updated

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. before post a question, please try to check error message with a bit more care. they may sometimes seem cryptic but mostly contain just what you need.  you need a newer java class file version of 61, which is java 17 that is released only few months ago.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the problem. It's not that the files are compiled by an **older** version of Java. It's that they're compiled by a **newer** version. You either need to update Java on the server, or downgrade Java on your own machine to match the server and then recompile everything.

Comment: and the latter is the best solution as Java16 is out of support, 17 is the current LTS.

Comment: Downloading a newer Java SE Development Kit will resolve the problem.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk17-archive-downloads.html?msclkid=66e5556cb3a111ecb57a6c21e35a5a9a

Comment: @Flea is completely right. The error message is a little bit misleading. You do not have to downgrade anything on your system. What I want to highlight at this point is, that for Minecraft Server, it must be the development kit (JDK) it is not sufficient to only install the latest runtime environment (JRE).

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading your java on your machine, like if the server needed java 8 and you have java 16, then uninstall java 16 and install java 8. it worked for me.

Comment: actually it is the opposite. from the error, OP needs a newer java version. welcome to stackoverflow. try to read just a bit more slowly and make sure you understand the question.